# how to get the value of multiple checkbox in php

Tags: php, checkbox

I have use the following code to select multiple value for selected checkbox  to delete it from  database table but when I am print_r its only shows keys for it not showing value for id.

I have use this code to get value in array:-

```
<?php
echo "Hiiiiiiiiii";
include("conn.php");
$sql="select * from test ";

$res=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
?>

<form name="form1" method="POST" action="">
    <table width="578" border="1" align="center" id="menu">
    <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>email</th>
    <th>phno</th>
 </tr>

<?php
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
 {
?>

 <tr>

    <td><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="<? echo $rows['id']; ?>"></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['id'];?></td>

    <td><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['emailid'];?></td>

    <td><?php echo $row['phno'];?></td>
    <?php
    echo"<td><a href='update.php?id=".$row['id']."'>Update</a></td>";
    ?>
 <?php
  }
 ?>  
 <tr><td><input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" id="delete"></td></tr></tr></table>

 <?php
// Check if delete button active, start this
$count = mysql_num_rows($res);
echo "$count";

if(isset($_POST['delete']))
{
    if(count($_POST['checkbox']) !=0)
    {
        $array = array("checkbox" => $_POST['checkbox']);
        print_r($array);
        $ids = implode(',', $array);
        echo "$ids";
        $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM test WHERE id IN ($ids)") or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
// if successful redirect to delete_multiple.php 
if($result)
    {
     echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=teach_delinquent.php\">";
     echo "SUCCESS";
    }

 ?>
```

Comment: You cant have id="checkbox[]" , this need to be set to an unique value.

Comment: $_POST['checkbox'] is already an array from postdata, so you dont need to make it anorher..

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST['checkbox']` array will contain only checked boxes:

```
$ids = array();
foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $val){
    $ids[] = (int) $val;
}
$ids = implode(',', $ids);
```

I've done the `foreach` to make all id's `INT` for security purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix of your question is as follows

Replace below line

```
$array = array("checkbox" => $_POST['checkbox']);
```

with

```
$array = $_POST['checkbox'];
```

or

```
$array = array_map('intval',$_POST['checkbox']); // if all values are integer ---for security
```

because $_POST['checkbox'] is already an array

Hope this will fix your problem

Answer (score -1):

First of all you need to count how many checkboxes are there

```
$counter = sizeof($_POST['checkbox']);
```

The run a loop to access all of these values

```
for($i=0;$i<=$counter;$i++){
    $checkbox_val = $_POST['checkbox'][$i];
}
```

That's all you need