# in a message system that displays messages in order, delete only selected message/messages

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have created a message system in php. My database holds the following tables:

```
users('user_id', 'name')
message_group('user_one', 'user_two', 'hash', 'date1', 'del1', 'del2')
messages('message_id', 'group_hash', 'from_id', 'message', 'date', 'read')
```

I have created the following code, which is using a while statement to extract all messages from my database.
Then by using a form I am trying to delete each message. The problem is that all messages are deleted. How can I delete only each one I want at a time? Consider that in order to delete a message I place in table messages_group del1=1 or del2=1 for user_one=$session_user_id or user_two=$session_user_id respectively

```
<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="delete_all" value="Delete All" style="margin-left:250px;"/>
</form>
```

here starts the php code

```
  $get_con = mysql_query(" SELECT `hash`, `user_one`, `user_two`, `date1` FROM `message_group` WHERE `user_one`='$session_user_id' OR `user_two`='$session_user_id' ORDER BY `date1` DESC ");       

//start while       
while($run_con = mysql_fetch_array($get_con)){          

$hash = $run_con['hash'];
$user_one = $run_con['user_one'];
$user_two = $run_con['user_two'];

      if($user_one == $session_user_id){
        $select_id = $user_two;
      }else{
        $select_id = $user_one;
      }

 $user_get = mysql_query(" SELECT `user_id`, `name` FROM `users` WHERE `user_id`='$select_id' ");
 $run_user = mysql_fetch_array($user_get);

 $user_id = $run_user['user_id'];


$a = mysql_query(" SELECT `user_one`, `user_two`, `hash`, `date1`, `del1`, `del2` FROM `message_group` WHERE `user_one`='$session_user_id' AND `hash`='$hash' AND `del1`='1'    ");
$b = mysql_query(" SELECT `user_one`, `user_two`, `hash`, `date1`, `del1`, `del2` FROM `message_group` WHERE `user_two`='$session_user_id' AND `hash`='$hash' AND `del2`='1'    ");

if(mysql_num_rows($a)==0 && mysql_num_rows($b)==0){

echo" $select_name </br> ";
$message_query = mysql_query(" SELECT `messages_id`, `from_id`, `message`, `date` FROM messages WHERE group_hash='$hash' ORDER BY `date` ASC ");

while($run_message = mysql_fetch_array($message_query)){
$message = $run_message['message'];
}

$ka = mysql_query("SELECT `messages_id`, `group_hash`, `from_id`, `message`, `date`, `read` FROM `messages` WHERE `group_hash`='$hash' AND `read`='1'  ");


if(mysql_num_rows($ka) != 0){   
echo " <a href='messages.php?hash=$hash'>$message ...</a>"; 
}



 if(isset($_POST['delete_all'])) {                      
 if($user_one == $session_user_id){ 
   mysql_query(" UPDATE `message_group` SET `del1`='1' WHERE `hash`='$hash' ");
 }else if($user_two == $session_user_id){ 
   mysql_query(" UPDATE `message_group` SET `del2`='1' WHERE `hash`='$hash' ");
 }  
   }
}//end while
```

Comment: running the page displays name, message and next a delete button each time

Comment: You should first consider creating a checkbox for each message in the form read from the database records.  Next, you need a php script that will read which checkboxes were selected by the user and then delete the ones indicated by the user.  I found an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12489675/how-to-get-the-value-of-multiple-checkbox-in-php